# add a new row in tableView every single month

Tags: swift, logic, nsdate

i have  a date say `2 March 2016` stored as `NSUserDefaults` and i want to add a new row in TableView every time a new Month is about to come , so what should i do for accomplishing this , IMO comparing the stored Date and Current Date and if 
in Curent Date a new Month is about to come in next 7 days  then add the 
row into table but i don't know where to start, anyone can give me some hint for checking  current date's next 7 days for  if a new months is about to come

and if my approach is not good enough then please correct me it'll be so appreciated by me and helpful for me

please see example for better understanding :

```
storedDate = 2 March 2016
currentDate = 26 March 2016

if CurrentDate + 1 Week == newMonth {
 //add the Row into TableView
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an Extension to NSDate and then do all sorts of day/month addition

This method you can use to add 7 days to the current date...

```
func dateByAddingDays(daysToAdd: Int)-> NSDate {
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = daysToAdd
    let newDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: self, options: .MatchFirst)
    return newDate!
}
```

This method to add months to current date

```
func dateByAddingMonths(monthsToAdd: Int)-> NSDate {
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.month = monthsToAdd
    let newDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: self, options: .MatchFirst)
    return newDate!
}
```

Then you need to check that date you created and see if it its a different month than the one that is stored..

```
 func compareMonths(newDate:NSDate)-> Bool {
    let today = NSDate()
    let todayPlusSeven = today.dateByAddingDays(7)
    return todayPlusSeven.isNextMonth(storedDate)
 }
```

Using this method to check if the months of 2 dates are the same

```
func isNextMonth(storedDate: NSDate)-> Bool {
    return isSameMonthAsDate(storedDate.dateByAddingMonth(1))
}

func isSameMonthAsDate(compareDate: NSDate)-> Bool {
    let comp1 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Month], fromDate: self)
    let comp2 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Month], fromDate: compareDate)
    return ((comp1.month == comp2.month) && (comp1.year == comp2.year))
}
```

An oldie but still goodie, is this page of Date helpers from Erica Sadun's github page [here](https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions/blob/master/NSDate%2BUtilities.m)  They are all in Obj-c but can be converted to swift easily enough.  I still reference it when i need help doing date math

Comment: Sure FYI I did this from my head so it might need some tweaking